# How can I implement a global high score or leaderboard in Python/Kivy for android?

Tags: python, kivy, leaderboard

I am working on a game which is written in Python/Kivy and would like to implement a global leaderboard. Does anyone have any suggestions or more preferably a working example which I can use?  I've stumbled across Redis but struggling to get my head around it for implementation and am not sure this is the right way to go. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Make sure to read the guidlines for posting question. Also, understand that stackoverflow is not a forum for promoting products.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am trying firebase realtime database. There is a YouTube video on how to do this.